# PCL library setup using vcpkg seems to be missing include files (pcl/visualization in particular)

Tags: include, point-cloud-library, vcpkg

My goal is to visualize a point cloud using PCL. This is possible according to their official tutorial ([link](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/cloud_viewer.html#cloud-viewer)). In the tutorial there is an include path pointing to cloud_viewer.h file (located under *visualization* folder). After a vcpkg install using "**vcpkg install pcl:x64-windows**" I couldn’t find the visualization folder. After some research it I found out that "*visualization*" does not come with default PCL install, but it is an optional feature ([link](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/030cfaa24de9ea1bbf0a4d9c615ce7312ba77af1/ports/pcl/CONTROL)). Then I used the "**vcpkg install pcl[vtk]:x64-windows --featurepackages**" and I am still missing the needed folder. If anyone could point out to me where am I making a mistake I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with you. It seems vcpkg is not a good choice for pcl library. Many people have the same problem with visualization module

Comment: Is there an alternative setup for PCL (other than vcpkg)?

Answer (score 0):

Using vcpkg does not provide all files, includes and headers for pcl.
I had the same issue, and downloading pcl all in one solved it.
You can find it here for example:  http://unanancyowen.com/en/pcl181/
Other thing that can help, is to use this command on vcpkg:

```
.\vcpkg install pcl:x64-windows-static
```